# How to create an OnKeyUp Event in textbox in asp?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I would like to know if there is any way to do this event without using JavaScript? I have tried but I can't do it, here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" EnableViewState="true" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Forms.Home" %>

    <div ID="FieldMovie"  runat="server">
        <label for="TxtTitle" class="form-label" runat="server">Title</label>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TxtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="TxtKind" class="form-label" runat="server">Kind</label>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TxtKind" runat="server" onkeyup="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyUp');"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TxtKindText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="TxtDuration" class="form-label" runat="server">Duration</label>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TxtDuration" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="TxtCalif" class="form-label" runat="server">Calification</label>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TxtCalifi" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" />

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrlName = Request.Params[Page.postEventSourceID];
        var args = Request.Params[Page.postEventArgumentID];

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
            
        }

        if (ViewState["Action"] == null)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
        else if (ViewState["Action"].ToString() == "Edit")
        {
            LoadData();
            if (args == "OnKeyUp")
            {
                OnKeyUp(ctrlName, args);
            }
            GrdMovies.Visible = false;
            FieldMovie.Attributes["style"] = "visibility: visible";
            SetFields(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));
        }
        
    }
    public void OnKeyUp(string ctrlName, string args)
   {
        TxtKindText.Text = TxtKind.Text;

   }
```

Basically the LoadData() function queries the database and obtains all the values, to display them in a grid, which we can select a value to edit, the SetFields() function does is fill the form with the values of the field that was selected in the grid which saves in "ViewState" the action to perform, which right now is to edit, then in the "kind" field is where I want what I am writing to be displayed.

The problem is that the onkeyup works, but the page is reloaded every time I write and the values of the other fields are lost, is there any other alternative?

Comment: javascript runs on the client-side, ASP runs on the server-side, that is why the function will send a message to the server and that will reload the page, if what you want is only `TxtKindText.Text = TxtKind.Text` why not add to the `TxtKind` control the javascript? `ID="TxtKind" onkeyup="document.getElementById('<%=TxtKindText.ClientID %>').value = this.value;"`

Comment: @balexandre  I forgot to mention that, what i really want is that when i write a number(id) in "TxtKind", it makes a query to the database to look for the value of the provided id and show it in "TxtKindText"

Comment: I would then create a new asp page for returning the results and on this form page that you mention, just call it through javascript and populate on keyup for example

Answer (score 0):

but, why not just have a simple text changed event that causes a post back?

I fail to see why we need on-key up?

the problem seems to be that your code setup does not correctly survive a post back, and it should without issue(s). So I assume you type some value in a text box, and then a pick list (that grid) is presented to the user. They select a value, and then you put the selected value from that grid back into the text box?

do, I have the above correct?

I mean, the txtKind could be a drop down list, could it not?

And why keyup? You type in value into text box, hit tab, display grid. User selects a row from the grid, you now can take that grid selection, shove whatever value into the text box, hide grid, and display your div. At this point, I fail to see why we not using plain jane standard events?

Any page correctly setup should survice post-backs. But you have a bunch of convoluted logic in your page load that may, or may not re-trigger loading of the data, or the grid. You don't want that.

Say we have a div with some controls.

Our page load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        DataTable rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ID = 6");
        General.FLoader(MyEditArea, rstData.Rows[0]);
    }
```

Now, above is just test code. but we are to display a customer in that div

So, we now have this:

[image]

Now, I think it is a strange kind of UI that we type somthing into a text box, and hide the edit, and display the grid (bad UI choice).

but, lets assume you type into the city text box in above, hit tab, and I now will display a list of cities based on what you typed in (for the user to select from the grid).

So, in above, I just typed in say Calgary for the city, and then hit tab key

So this:

[image]

Well, the markup for the city text box is this:

```
                <label>City</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server"  Width="140" f="City"
                    OnTextChanged="tCity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/> <br />
                <label>Province</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" Width="75" f="Province"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

So, I have a text changed event.

So, in my code behind, I now have this code:

```
    protected void tCity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tCity.Text != "" )
        {
            // display grid of hotels based on user typed in City
            lblSel.Text = "Please select a Hotel from " + tCity.Text;

            SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
                new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE City = @City");
            
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tCity.Text;
            DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            Debug.Print("row count = " + rstData.Rows.Count.ToString());
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            // now hide our edit area, show grid view
            MyGridPick.Style.Add("display", "normal");
            MyEditArea.Style.Add("display", "none");

        }
    }
```

So, it loads the grid pick list based on city, hides our edit div, display the grid view to select a city. So, we now see this:

[image]

Now, the gridview, was nothing speical, but was this:

```
    <div id="MyGridPick" runat="server" style="display:none;width:40%">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSel" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID"  cssclass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"                />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" ItemStyle-Width="120px"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View"   >
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="MyCenter"/>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="MyCenter" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="bView" runat="server" Text="Select" CssClass="btn"
                            OnClick="bView_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

But, ONLY what is imporant in above, is the button we dropped into the grid, and to select that given row.

That code is this:

(grab hotel, maybe database PK)

then put selected value into our edit area, hide grid, show edit area.

We have this code for the button click:

```
    protected void bView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int? PKID = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"] as int?;

        // grab data from the grid, or pull via sql query based on PKID (hotel id)

        string HotelName = gRow.Cells[3].Text;

        // put selection into HotelName on our user edit area

        txtHotel.Text = HotelName;

        // now hide grid, show edit area
        // now hide our edit area, show grid view
        MyGridPick.Style.Add("display", "none");
        MyEditArea.Style.Add("display", "normal");
```

That's it.

Just clean, simple code. No need for view state testing and all that jazz.

So, when I select a grid row, then I shove the hotel name into the text box in my edit area, and hide grid, show edit area.

(I'll click on last row, so my hotel text box now gets updated to madd trapper.

eg this:

[image]

Since my code was respecting the page event model, and I ONLY load my data, and don't re-load (and repsect !IsPostBack), then it all works, and works will realtive simple and clean code.

I VERY much fail to see why you have all that fancy view state code, and fancy testing of view state and all that logic?

Perhaps the problem is reverse. (we display grid, select a row), display details, and hide grid. But, either way, note how even my grid row button click was a plane jane asp.net button click. (I don't bother with the GridView edits - they are panful, and not required in most cases).

I also of course get fast tired of typing in data pull over and over. So, I have these two helper routines used in above:

```
    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And I also have a routine that you can pass a data row, and "div", and it loads up the div based on my "made up" f="Data base column" attribuote.

(that is what floader) does. I can post that code if you wish.

As above shows, just clean simple code, and no JavaScript was required.

Of course, I think I would drop in a jQuery.UI dialog. And pop the grid in a dialog popup form. And the above code server side could drive most of this, and including the popping up the "div" with a jQuery.UI dialog for this.

And I have zero view state code - and I don't see the need for any at all here.